# For every integer $y$, there is an integer $x$ such that $x + y < 0$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

> Determine the truth value of the following statement and explain your answer. 
>  **Statement:** For every integer $y$, there is an integer $x$ such that $x + y < 0$.

---

I think the truth value is true but I'm not sure how to explain why since we're not allowed to use examples in our explanation. I tried converting the statement into the following formula

$$\forall y \exists x \left( x + y < 0 \right)$$

but don't quite know where to go from there.

Can someone please confirm my answer and help me explain it? I will gladly appreciate it!

Comment: Your formal  version of the claim introduces a "$10$" where it ought to have a "$0$" but is otherwise ok.  For the claim itself, taking $x=-1-y$ suffices.

Comment: @lulu Oh sorry, that was a typo. I will correct it. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression to hold is
$$x+y<0$$

Now let $x=-y-k$
expression becomes
$$(-y-k)+y<0 \Leftrightarrow$$
$$/\text{ Associative rule} : -y-k=-k-y/$$
$$-k-y+y<0\Leftrightarrow$$
$$-k<0\Leftrightarrow$$
$$0<k$$

Now we can select any $k>0$ and the proposition will hold.